# для чего нужны ;; в for?

Tags: c++

Вопрос такой зачем нужны две точки с запятой в этой кусочке кода

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int  digit = 0;
    char exit = 'y';

    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Введите число: ";
        cin >> digit;
        cout << "Квадрат " << digit << " = " << digit * digit;
        cout << " \nПродолжить ввод числ - Y,Выйти - N: ";
        cin >> exit;
        if (exit != 'y' && exit != 'Y')
            break;


    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что `for` без трех частей в заголовке не бывает. Здесь просто показано, что они пустые - просто бесконечный цикл, с выходом в теле через `break`.

Answer (score 10):

Конструкция `for (;;) {…}` - это бесконечный цикл. Такой же как `while (1) {…}`

Если отвечать на поставленный вопрос, то два символа `;` - это разделители трех параметров оператора `for`, все из которых пустые.

**UPD**

[Ссылка на документацию по for от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/for-statement-cpp)

**UPD2**

`for` можно рассматривать не как отдельный оператором, а как "синтаксический сахар" для `while`

```
for (A;B;C) D;
```

почти эквивалентно

```
{
  A;
  while (B)
  {
    D;
    C;
  }
}
```

Но существенная разница в том, что если выражение `B` пустое, то оно считается тождественно истинным.

Comment: во-первых, эквивалентность с `while` не верна — отличается видимость переменных объявленных в `A`, а главное `continue` будет вести себя по-другому... во-вторых, `for` в языке был изначально (по крайней мере со времён K&R), так что, называя его «сахаром», можно прийти к тому, что все циклы — просто сахар для `if` и `goto`...

Comment: Если вы перечитаете первое издание K&R, то увидите, что переменные всегда объявлялись до цикла, а не внутри `for`, как сейчас.

Comment: наверное оно так — не буду проверять... но как ни крути, `for` всегда был отдельным циклом...

Comment: Поправил ответ, смягчив формулировки.